# patching routers with ansible raw module, but ansible is not respoding after the patching

Tags: ansible

in the ansible script we do an raw command:

```
- name: Install firmware
  raw: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "upgrade primary {{ ftp_server }} {{ firmware }}"
  register: patch_output
  tags:
    - patch_firmware
```

This takes a while because the firmware is 80 Mb and this is downloaded from an ftp server. After that the routers flashes the firmware and does an reboot.

The ansible-playbook hangs and is not comming back. I looked at async but this is not available for raw. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your router reboots without terminating the TCP connection, you have to define an appropriate [timeout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#command-timeout).